# How prove $\frac{\sin{a}-\sin{c}}{a-c}>\frac{\sin{b}-\sin{d}}{b-d}$

Tags: inequality

**Question:**

> let $a,b,c,d$ such $0<a<b<c<d<\pi$, show that
>   $$\dfrac{\sin{a}-\sin{c}}{a-c}>\dfrac{\sin{b}-\sin{d}}{b-d}$$

My idea: if we use Mean value theorem
then there exsit
$$\xi\in(a,c),\eta\in(b,d)$$
such
$$\cos{\xi}=\dfrac{\sin{a}-\sin{c}}{a-c},\cos{\eta}=\dfrac{\sin{b}-\sin{d}}{b-d}$$
but for $\cos{\xi}$ and $\cos{\eta}$, which is greater? we cannot know, because maybe we have $\xi=\eta$.

So how to prove this inequality?

Comment: This is Jensen's inequality, isn't it?

Comment: @Bombyxmori,I fell is not

Comment: Check Rudin's real and complex analysis, page 61. This looks very similar.

Comment: I think this is just the geometric form of Jensen's inequality for $\sin[x]$, the only difference is you have to shift $b$ equal to $c$ to change it into Rudin's form. But this should not be difficult to prove.

Answer (score 6):

Draw a figure. Looking at the slopes of various segments you then can immediately verify that the concavity of $\sin$ in the interval $[0,\pi]$ implies
$${\sin c-\sin a\over c-a}>{\sin c-\sin b\over c-b}>{\sin d-\sin b\over d-b}\ .$$